# Have a optional parameter in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure that has a `State` parameter as optional, so if I pass state it should query table using both parameter, if I am not passing the state parameter I only need to query table with the template parameter.

How I can do that?

This is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Get_TempName]
     @TemType varchar(50),
     @State varchar(50) = 'N/A'
AS
BEGIN
     SET NOCOUNT ON;

     SELECT 
         [TempType],
         [TempName],
         [State]
     FROM 
         [Template] WITH (NOLOCK) 
     WHERE
         TempType = @TempType 
         AND [State] = @State
END
```

Comment: I see you are using the NOLOCK hint? Is this common at your workplace? Do you throw this hint everywhere? Do you know the real implications of that? http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Create[dbo].[Get_TempName]
  @TemType    varchar(50)
 ,@State    varchar(50) = NULL

AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

 SELECT 
   [TempType]
  ,[TempName]
  ,[State]

 FROM [Template]  WITH (NOLOCK) 
  where TempType = @TempType 
 and (([State] IS NULL) OR ([State] = @State))

 END
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work because you have [State] = NULL which will never evaluate to true. Your whole where predicate is off here.

Comment: Sean, let me copy and paste the question: so if I pass state it should query table using both parameter, if I am not passing the state parameter I only need to query table with the template parameter.

So if the State is not passed, then State becomes automatically NULL.

Comment: But [State] will NEVER equal NULL and the logic is not what the OP asked for. They want ALL states when a state isn't passed in, not rows that don't have a state defined. Even if the logic was correct, it won't work because it would have to be [State] IS NULL, not = NULL.

Comment: Almost there...you have the IS NULL part correct but you should be checking the parameter, not the table value. Once you fix that it will look exactly like the code from Indian. :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use `OR` condition with `Is Null` check. Also pass `NULL` in `@state` parameter when you don't want to use it in filter

```
Create[dbo].[Get_TempName]
  @TemType    varchar(50)
 ,@State    varchar(50) 

AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;

 SELECT 
   [TempType]
  ,[TempName]
  ,[State]

 FROM [Template]  WITH (NOLOCK) 
  where TempType = @TempType 
 and ([State] = @State or @state is null)

 END
```

Answer (score 1):

you could do everything in one select statement, but this can have adverse performance implications. It is usually better to separate it out into separate selects based on the parameters.

```
Create[dbo].[Get_TempName]
@TemType    varchar(50)
,@State    varchar(50) 

AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF(@State IsNull)
    SELECT 
    [TempType]
    ,[TempName]
    ,[State]
    FROM [Template]  WITH (NOLOCK) 
    where TempType = @TempType 
 ELSE
    SELECT 
    [TempType]
    ,[TempName]
    ,[State]
    FROM [Template]  WITH (NOLOCK) 
    where TempType = @TempType 
    and [State] = @State
END
```

Comment: This will work but is highly likely to be a performance problem because the execution plan gets cached for one branch and not the other.

Comment: Here is an excellent article which explains the performance issue of this type of approach. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/09/15/multiple-execution-paths/

Comment: thanks for the article.  So based on that, the most performant method would be to create sub procedures for each filter type, and just have the If statement call each sub Proc?

Comment: If you follow the two query approach then yes. I would prefer to do something like what Indian posted for this type of query though. Depending on the performance of that it might need to have the recompile option added.